# error with MySQL load data infile field with double quotes

Tags: mysql, mysql-loadfile

I have .csv file data like this:

```
"UPRR 38 PAN AM "M"","1"
```

and I loaded data into table using below command which is having two columns (`a` and `b`).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:\monthly_data.csv'
INTO TABLE test_data_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

But when I select table, it's giving unexpected results which is shown below.

`a` contains:

```
UPRR 38 PAN AM "M","1
```

... and b is `NULL`.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053530/load-data-from-csv-file-where-doublequote-was-used-as-the-escape-character can help?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all the instances of "Double quote double quote" in your file

either A. open the files and find replace them 
or B. make a script to open the files and replace the extra quote that is messing it up

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Thus `"` is not a regular character any more. It's a special character that has a special meaning: it highlights the start and end of a column value. If you want to type a `"` that does *not* behave that way you need to escape it. The [RFC 4180 - Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) document explains how to do that:

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>          appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>          another double quote

```
a;b
"UPRR 38 PAN AM ""M""";1
```

As they say, garbage in, garbage out ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alvaro but i have 1 million records with same case, how can i add another double quote to escape it.

Comment: Why do you have 1 million records of broken data in the first place?